# ChunkVNC gives error while compiling winvnc.exe

Tags: remote-desktop, tightvnc, ultravnc, vnc-viewer

I have installed ChunkVNC_3_3_1 . When i use compiler.exe and create exe files it gives error like

```
WARNING : Running WinVNC without setting a password is a dangerous security risk!
Until you set a password, WinVNC will not accept incoming connections.
```

I have replaced winvnc.exe of old version with latest version 1.1.9.6 in application path of ChunkVNC_3_3_1 . Why this error comes when compiling using comiler.exe. In Compiler.exe i have filled WAN,viewer,server port and Instantsupport password properly while using compiler.exe.
So please help me